# Ignore or disable mobile viewport resize when focus on input in iPhone

Tags: html, iphone, mobile

If you open site [migreview.com](https://migreview.com) on iPhone and choise some input element then window size will be changed. What I can do for disable changing of mobile viewport?

Comment: Add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>` to your `<head>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `meta name="viewport"` like this:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>`
inside the head tag, this will prevent it from being scaled by the user.